# Tesseract 3.05 SetImage error

Tags: c++, tesseract

Trying to make simple app with tesseract. I included all libs\h files, add tesseract and leptonica lib, but when I try to use this:

```
Pix *pix = pixRead("C:\\2.tiff");
myOCR->SetImage(pix);
```

I have error

Error    LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetImage(struct Pix const *)" (?SetImage@TessBaseAPI@tesseract@@QAEXPBUPix@@@Z) referenced in function _main

How can I resolve it?

Tesseract - ocr version : 3.04.00
Leptonica version : leptonica-1.73 (Aug 18 2016, 11:32:05) [MSC v.1900 LIB Debug
 x86]

SetImage work well with Tesseract 3.02 but there is no ChoiceIterator that I need